# iphone - animation in the simulator works fine but in device nothing happens?

Tags: iphone

```
-(void) DownRoll1 { 
    down1.image = up1.image;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.2];
    CGPoint destination = CGPointMake(296,440);
    down1.center = destination;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: did you step through the code on the device?  the traditional reason for images to not load on the device when they work on the simulator is that the device has case-sensitive filenames but the simulator doesn't, so make sure your files don't have a capital "B" in the name...

Comment: that was the problem! thanks.
btw any suggestion to move part of the code to viewdidload or viewDidAppear for better performance ?

Comment: posted answer below so you can click the check-mark on it.  can you clarify what you mean by performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was: check that your filenames will match on the case-sensitive device.

if you want to make something happen more quickly when the user hits the "shuffle" button, you could pre-load the image in your viewDidLoad method, and just not show it until later.

Comment: how can i preload it if it come randomize from the array?

Comment: you can pick your random number early; as long as you don't tell the user you've made up your mind about which image, it doesn't matter.